# Problems with variable when calling a method in main,

Tags: java

I am trying to call this method in main in order to excecute my project..But I have problems with variables. It said to me: g cannot be resolved to a variable...How can I solve this? What can I do? Please help me...Thank you

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Cycle
{

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
 int gjeresia_e_kornizes = 300;
 int gjatesia_e_kornizes = 200;
 g.setColor(Color.red);
 g.fillRect(0,0,gjeresia_e_kornizes, gjatesia_e_kornizes);
 g.setColor(Color.red);
 int skaji_majtas = 105;
 int lart =70;
 int gjeresia = 90;
 int lartesia = 60;
 g.drawRect(skaji_majtas, lart, gjeresia, lartesia);
 int diametri = 40;
 g.fillOval(skaji_majtas+gjeresia-diametri,lart, diametri, diametri);
 }

 public static void main (String[] args){
 // test your Cycle class hereafter

   Cycle cycle = new Cycle();

   //instanciate a Graphics g and pass it to the paintComponent method
   cycle.paintComponent(g);

 }

}
```

Comment: g is not in scope in the main method.  note that it is neither declared nor defined in the scope of the main method.  read this until you understand scope: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Where did you instantiate your Graphics object? It's not there.

Comment: You never allocate "g" in main, it's undefined.

Comment: But how can I instantiate it? Can you help me

Answer (score 1):

This is basics.

In your main method you are using a variable g, which is not defined.

Comment: But how can I define it? Can you help me

Comment: Check your other messages you have posted on Stackoverflow where people have given you a full solution to your problem. Currently you are repeating your question which is not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate the graphics object yourself, it is managed for you. Here a working version of your code that extends from `JPanel`. Have a look at it and continue from there.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Cycle extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int gjeresia_e_kornizes = 300;
        int gjatesia_e_kornizes = 200;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, gjeresia_e_kornizes, gjatesia_e_kornizes);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        int skaji_majtas = 105;
        int lart = 70;
        int gjeresia = 90;
        int lartesia = 60;
        g.drawRect(skaji_majtas, lart, gjeresia, lartesia);
        int diametri = 40;
        g.fillOval(skaji_majtas + gjeresia - diametri, lart, diametri, diametri);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cycle cycle = new Cycle();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Cycle.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(cycle);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a `Graphics` class object(as Graphics is an abstract class you can pass any of its sub class' object e.g. DebugGraphics, Graphics2D) which you will have to pass to that method.

if you are using any IDE it has to give compile time error toy you as you have not declared any such variable called 'g'

Comment: How can i create this object? Can you help me please?

Comment: VD: Seriously? I believe Graphics is an abstract class.

Comment: @KodingKid agree, i could have mentioned that! i have edited the same, thanks for correction